# strcpy() em string de struct

Tags: c, string, struct, alocação

Eu tenho uma `struct Time` que possui um vetor `char name[30]`, o problema começa quando eu tento copiar um valor para essa *string* com a função `strcpy()`, segue o código da `stuct`:

```
typedef struct Time{
  char name[30];
  int pnts;
  int vit, emp, der;
  int gf, gt;

  struct Time *next;
  struct Time *prev;
}time;
```

e aqui a função que implementa o s`trcpy()`:

```
void addTime(campeonato *c, char name[]){
  time t;
  strcpy(t.name, name);
  t.next = NULL;
  t.pnts = t.vit = t.emp = t.der = t.gt = t.gf = 0;

  if(c->first == NULL){
    c->first =  &t;
    t.prev = NULL;
  } else {
    time *p = c->first;
    while(p->next != NULL){
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = &t;
    t.prev = p;
  }
}
```

A `main()` está assim:

```
campeonato c;
createCamp(&c, "Brasileirao");
addTime(&c, "Palmeiras");
time *t = c.first;

printf("%s", t->name);

return 0;
```

O valor do *print* para `t->name` é sempre lixo.

Comment: Faça um [mcve]. Talvez até descubra o problema sozinho, se não, pelo menos teremos mais chance de ajudá-lo. Na forma atual não tem todas informações e fica bem difícil responder a pergunta. Talvez o problema esteja em `campeonato`.

Comment: Para tornar essa programação mais segura, como o char name tem tamanho definido, eu usaria o strncpy em vez do strcpy para garantir que não ocorra o overflow do array.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável. Não tentei deixar bonitinho ou melhorar os outros problemas do código, mas esse está resolvido. O objeto do time está sendo criado localmente na função `addTime()`, portanto no *stack*, quando sai da função, não tem mais acesso ao objeto, por isso não consegue acessá-lo. O correto nesse caso é, ou alocar o objeto em `main()` e passar um ponteiro para ele, ou alocar no *heap* para sobreviver ao fim da função. Mais ou menos assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Time{
  char name[30];
  int pnts;
  int vit, emp, der;
  int gf, gt;
  struct Time *next;
  struct Time *prev;
} time;

typedef struct campeonato { time *first; } campeonato;

void addTime(campeonato *c, char name[]) {
    time *t = malloc(sizeof(time));
    strcpy(t->name, name);
    t->next = NULL;
    t->pnts = t->vit = t->emp = t->der = t->gt = t->gf = 0;
    if (c->first == NULL) {
        c->first =  t;
        t->prev = NULL;
    } else {
        time *p = c->first;
        while (p->next != NULL) p = p->next;
        p->next = t;
        t->prev = p;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    campeonato c = { .first = NULL };
    addTime(&c, "Santos");
    time *t = c.first;
    printf("%s", t->name);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/A1ahGK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vdfnnwbb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/StringIn.c).